# SparkNLP requirement Failed

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib, pipeline

I am trying to run unified SparkNLP and MLlib pipeline on spark 2.3 but I got the error when I fit the dataset on it.

```
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(descfeature)
```

The follow is error:-

```
 requirement failed: Input type must be string type but 
 gotArrayType(StructType(StructField(annotatorType,StringType,true), 
 StructField(start,IntegerType,false), 
 StructField(end,IntegerType,false), 
 StructField(result,StringType,true), 
StructField(metadata,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true)),true).
```

My Pipelin is

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(documentAssembler,tokenizer,stemmer,stopWordsRemover,vectorizer,lda))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stopWordRemover doesn't work on annotations, but on strings. For the conversion from annotation values to strings, you need to add a finisher between stemmer and stopWordRemover:

```
val finisher = new Finisher()
    .setInputCols("filtered")
    .setOutputCols("filtered")
    .setOutputAsArray(true)
```

If no outputCols are defined, the output columns default to "finished_${inputColumn}".

As the stopwordRemover expects an array of string, you need to activate the option setOutputAsArray.

The Finisher is explained in more detail at the Spark NLP page: http://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/components.html

Comment: Not on Strings but Array of Strings. :)

Comment: Hello,I am getting this error,  field "filtered" does not exists.I am setting "filtered" as output column from stopwords remover and setting it as input colum for countvectorizer. If you know this, please tell me.

Comment: Basically it is not showing anything in normalize and finisher coulmn,

Comment: I presume you didn't define the output column's name of the Finisher - please check my edited answer. Tip: use the function show() on your dataframe to investigate the output of the Finisher (or other stages)